# fp and macro question

Tags: macros, expansion, fp, fragile

I try to feed macros doing FP calculations into other macros doing the same, and face problems with macro expansion. The usual "protect" trick didn't work for me. Any hints?

An example is below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fp}
\newcommand{\calculation}[2]{%
\FPeval\X{round(#1 + #2,1)}%
\X%
}

% shall return result of some expression if argument is "XXX"
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{XXX}=\z@\FPeval\result{round(1+2+3,1)}\result\fi%      
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% writes 6.0
0: \foo{XXX}

% works fine: gives 30.0 
1: \calculation{10}{20}

% now try to insert expression from 0 into calculation: doesn't work
2: \calculation{\foo{XXX}}{20}

% store result of foo in Y: works: gives 6.0
\FPset\Y{\protect\foo{XXX}}
3: \FPprint\Y

% inserting Y into calculation
4: \calculation{\Y}{20}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it will work, `\FPeval` is not expandable. But you could try `xfp` instead of `fp`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand{\calculation}[2]{%
\fpeval{round(#1 + #2,1)}%
}

% shall return result of some expression if argument is "XXX"
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{XXX}=\z@\fpeval{round(1+2+3,1)}\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% writes 6.0
0: \foo{XXX}

% works fine: gives 30.0
1: \calculation{10}{20}

% now try to insert expression from 0 into calculation: doesn't work
2: \calculation{\foo{XXX}}{20}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick!